# Cypress open immediately gets stuck at loading screen

Tags: cypress

I run Linux 20.04.

Cypress open gets stuck loading when booting up.
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzeJh.png)

When doing a fresh install on the desktop with "npm install -D cypress" I can choose the e2e test category, it creates the default folder structure and config then it gets stuck on the same screen.
Cypress run dosen't do anything at all.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues?

Comment: Someone asked about the same thing on a gist of mine yesterday: https://gist.github.com/textbook/3377dda14efe4449772c2377188c3fa8?permalink_comment_id=4338114#gistcomment-4338114. Reported on GitHub too: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24166.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I used an older node version, that's what was causing my problem. It got fixed when i updated